# Mariadb on Raspbian: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, socket, mariadb

I'm setting up a "clean" image for my home Raspberry pi running the latest Raspbian, and I'm finding a small problem when installing the mariadb database.

So far, the steps I've taken are the following:

```
  sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server

  sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add the following lines to my.cnf:

```
  [mysqld]
  datadir=/mnt/RaspberryData/mysql
  socket=/mnt/RaspberryData/mysql/mysql.sock
  [client]
  port=3306
  socket=/mnt/RaspberryData/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The path `/mnt/RaspberryData/mysql`contains the database info of my previous installation, which was configured through a hard link. This may or may not be the issue.

Then execute:

```
  sudo sytemctl start mariadb
  journalctl -u mariadb
```

And here's when I have the issue:

```
Jun 22 19:18:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.22 database server...
Jun 22 19:18:34 raspberrypi mysqld[2623]: 2020-06-22 19:18:34 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 2623 ...
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Jun 22 19:18:35 raspberrypi /etc/mysql/debian-start[2662]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

As you can see, there's some kind of update process that is trying to connect through a socket located in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`but that path has nothing (Only a `mysqld.pid` file).

I'm guessing the guides on how to move the data from one location to another omitted some process or whatnot, as I can actually get into the database and execute queries. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure when mysql is starting it's reading `/etc/mysqld/my.cnf`, and it's not being ignored in favor of `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: There is no my.cnf under /etc/my.cnf, so yeah. Also, it seems mariadb is using the path linked on /etc/mysql/my.cnf, as the old databases stored in my new path are being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was left in my configuration.

Bear in mind that this may is a bit overkill (read: modifying more files than it should), but unless someone wiser comes to teach me, I'll stick happy with it:

So, let's start by reading the `my.cnf`file:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
```

My issue here was that there was an upgrade process trying to use a socket defined *somewhere*. Obviously, "somewhere" meant (hopefully) "in a configuration file" so I dove in these files:

Going `sudo nano`on the files listed (specially on those under `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf` showed me several entries for socket that kept the original value on the /run/ folder. So I changed it to the new folder "just in case." It turns out one of the files listed as a comment that I should `Not forget to update debian.cnf if you change the socket`. Well, thanks, Mr. Database builder, because you mostly give me the real answer, as `debian.cnf`, even though it has a huge "DO NOT TOUCH" comment above, has this section below:

```
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Which seems to be exactly the process that was crashing.

So, tl;dr: Go through all the files listed on the `my.cnf` and change the socket value just in case. Also `debian.cnf`. And if you feel adventurous enough, change only `debian.cnf`and please tell me what happened.

I have a shitload of stuff to install now that I have the database working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message after I updated from Raspberry Stretch to Buster.
The `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is not empty (`ls -all`) but you can't configure the data inside.

I've looked at all of the files (`sudo nano`) and one file was the answer to my problem! Luckily the old configuration (`/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf.old`) was saved!

- Save the new file `50-server.cnf` under a new name in case things go wrong example: `50-server_very_old`
- Use `sudo nano` to open `50-server.cnf.old` and take away the `old` and save to make it the new version `50-server.cnf`.
- Restart the system and everything works as before!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you could explain why you propose to edit the file `50-server.cnf.old` just to rename it. Wouldn't a `cp 50-server.cnf.old 50-server.cnf` do just the same?