# start mysql/mariaDB service after datadir change

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed the mariadb server and create a root user with a password
with

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Since I use a Rasperri Pi I want to swap the DB to an external hard disk. For this I have taken [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/change-default-mysql-mariadb-data-directory-in-linux/)

After I changed the cnf files (all under /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/ and also the debian.cnf file under /etc/mysql) starting the mysql service fails:

```
 $ sudo service mysql start
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The log says that a test file could not be created:

```
$systemctl status mariadb.service
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.31 database server...
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch mysqld[4694]: 2021-10-30 22:56:31 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 4694 ...
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch mysqld[4694]: 2021-10-30 22:56:31 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/raspberrypitouch.lower-test
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch mysqld[4694]: [101B blob data]
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch mysqld[4694]: 2021-10-30 22:56:31 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 30 22:56:31 raspberrypitouch systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.
```

after an extensive search, I found and ruled out the following possible causes:

1. [apparmour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory) and [SELinux](https://debugah.com/how-to-solve-mysql-error-cant-create-test-file-xxx-lower-test-8421/) are blocking access to the new directory -> they are not installed

   ```
   getenforce
   -bash: getenforce: command not found
   ```

   and

   ```
   aa-status

   -bash: aa-status: command not found
   ```
2. [typo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638134/cant-start-mariadb-after-moving-datadir-to-external-drive)

   I have copied all paths and a typo would be a really poor reason to be busy for two days
3. [Missing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#cant-create-test-file) [permissions](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=487318)

   I have copied with this, so the permissions should be correct: `cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/`

   parent folder

   ```
   /media/pi/DBDRIVE $ ls -l
   total 20
   drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 16384 Oct 29 12:25 lost+found
   drwxrwxrwx 6 mysql mysql  4096 Oct 30 23:07 MariaDB
   ```

   the db Folder itself

   ```
   /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB $ ls -l

   total 110632

   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    16384 Oct 30 15:30 aria_log.00000001
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       52 Oct 30 15:30 aria_log_control
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root         0 Oct 30 13:02 debian-10.3.flag
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql      976 Oct 30 15:30 ib_buffer_pool
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Oct 30 15:30 ibdata1
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Oct 30 15:30 ib_logfile0
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Oct 30 13:02 ib_logfile1
   -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        0 Oct 30 13:02 multi-master.info
   drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 30 13:02 mysql
   drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 30 17:50 mysqld
   drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 30 13:02 performance_schema
   drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 30 15:12 testDB
   ```

   the drive

   ```
   /media/pi/DBDRIVE $ ls -l
   total 20
   drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 16384 Oct 29 12:25 lost+found
   drwxrwxrwx 7 mysql mysql  4096 Oct 30 23:58 MariaDB
   ```

   pi

   ```
   /media/pi $ ls -l
   total 4
   drwxr-xr-x 4 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 30 16:53 DBDRIVE
   ```

   media

   ```
   /media $ ls -l
   total 4
   drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 31 01:42 pi
   ```
4. [wrong format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878150/how-to-start-mariadb-on-boot-after-external-drive-is-mounted/60902537#60902537) [for external drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58081/unable-to-start-mysql-after-moving-it-to-usb-memory-stick)

   ```
   df -Th
   Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

   /dev/root      ext4       29G  3.8G   25G  14% /
   devtmpfs       devtmpfs  776M     0  776M   0% /dev
   tmpfs          tmpfs     937M     0  937M   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs          tmpfs     937M  8.6M  928M   1% /run
   tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
   tmpfs          tmpfs     937M     0  937M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat      253M   49M  204M  20% /boot
   tmpfs          tmpfs     188M  4.0K  188M   1% /run/user/1000
   /dev/sda       ext4      916G  186M  870G   1% /media/pi/DBDRIVE
   ```
5. [error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211190/mariadb-datadir-change-location-raspberry-pi) [in a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock/31984482#31984482) [cnf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

   [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594430/mariadb-on-raspbian-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket) is basically the same case but the solution does not work for me

- [my.cnf](https://pastebin.com/bPLaa2Mu)
- [50-client.cnf](https://pastebin.com/pNa76h1L)
- [50-mysql-clients.cnf](https://pastebin.com/DhnfKeyJ)
- [50-mysqld_safe.cnf](https://pastebin.com/wVhRyT2a)
- [50-server.cnf](https://pastebin.com/N3kmtc5c)
- [debian.cnf](https://pastebin.com/7CeRs2YP)

Every hint in the right direction is appreciated

**Why can't I start the service ?**

Comment: +1 for the research effort. What error do you get if you run `sudo -u mysql touch /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/raspberrypitouch.lower-test` ?

Comment: @Haxiel `sudo -u mysql touch /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/raspberrypitouch.lower-test
touch: cannot touch '/media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/raspberrypitouch.lower-test': Permission denied`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you check the permissions on /media, /media/pi, & /media/pi/DBDRIVE ? They should all have at least execute permissions so that the mariadb/mysql process can get into the MariaDB directory. If anything is missing, it can be fixed with a `sudo chmod 755 directory`.

Comment: @Haxiel media was missing the read permissions, thank you a lot

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've added the details as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the issue was reproducible manually by running `sudo -u mysql touch /media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/raspberrypitouch.lower-test`. This resulted in a 'permission denied' error.

Since the question shows that the 'MariaDB' directory is fully owned by the 'mysql' user, the problem would most likely be with one of the parent directories - '/media', '/media/pi', & '/media/pi/DBDRIVE'. These directories need at least execute permissions (for all users) so that the 'mysql' user can access the '/media/pi/DBDRIVE/MariaDB/' directory.

OP has confirmed that the /media directory was missing the required permissions, and that adding them fixed the issue.

Related note from the MariaDB knowledgebase: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#cant-create-test-file